# How to get a XML file from assets via a thread in Android?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, xml-parsing

Here is my scenario.

I have `MainActivity.java` in which I am calling the thread like this

```
private void callXMLParserThread() {

    String filePath = "file:///android_asset/weather_conditions.xml";
    parserThread = new XMLParserThread(context, filePath);
    parserThread.start();

}
```

and here is my `XMLParserThread.java`

```
public class XMLParserThread extends Thread {

Context context;
String fileName;
XMLParser xmlParser;

public XMLParserThread(Context context, String fileName) {

    this.context = context;
    this.fileName = fileName;
}

@Override
public void run() {

    xmlParser = new XMLParser();

    String xmlResponse = null;
    try {
        xmlResponse = xmlParser.getXmlFromFile(context, fileName);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.d("xmlResponse", xmlResponse + "");

    super.run();
}

}
```

*Notice:* In run() method I'm calling the another method `getXmlFromFile()` resides in `XMLParser.java`

Now here is my `getXmlFromFile()` method.

```
public String getXmlFromFile(Context context, String fileName) throws IOException {

    Log.e("fileName", fileName);

    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = context.getAssets().open(fileName);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
    ByteArrayOutputStream buf = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int result = bis.read();
    while(result != -1) {
      byte b = (byte)result;
      buf.write(b);
      result = bis.read();
    }        
    return buf.toString();
}
```

**Problem**

When I execute the code it throws the `java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:///android_asset/weather_conditions.xml at xml.parser.XMLParser.getXmlFromFile(XMLParser.java:43)`

where the line no 43 is `is = context.getAssets().open(fileName);` in my `getXmlFromFile()` method

Also, I'm sure the file exists in the assets folder. Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: Where is the folder? I think your path is absolute, but if I'm not wrong apps cannot access to the root folder. You can take a look to the documentation: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, you can just say as below without that "file:///..." part.

```
String filePath = "weather_conditions.xml";
```

Answer (score 1):

When you define path from assets, write only path of sub-folder of assets.

If you have xml file under:

```
assets/android_asset/weather_conditions.xml
```

so file path should be:

```
String filePath = "android_asset/weather_conditions.xml";
```

BTW, you have helper in your code:

```
is = context.getAssets().open(fileName);
```

`context.getAssets()` means open `assets` folder and find out path there.